# How to tell which program is using my disk?

Tags: windows, windows-8

Windows 8 refuses to let me unmount a harddrive saying that it's in use.

I can't find which program is using it.

Is there a program  that will give me a list of all programs using a hard-drive

Answer (score 12):

[process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), from Mark Russinovitch Sysinternals (now owned by Microsoft) can do this:

in the Find menu, click "Find Handle or DLL..."

in there, type what you are looking for (in your case, for example, `f:` if that is the name of the disk you wish to know which program(s) is(are) still using)

it will then display all the processes that are using a handle or dll containing the string you were looking for (ex: containing `f:` , thus listing all programs still using something on `f:` or having their current directory set somewhere on `f:`)

(You can use the same thing to find out which process has open a given specific file, etc. )

Comment: +1 because this is a more specific answer: find out which drive is being used.

Comment: I would also suggest using f:\ instead of f:, since :f finds also some irrelevant founds such as : `firefox.exe 2172 Section \Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\87cHWNDInterface:e02d2`

Answer (score 7):

I suggest to use the [Windows Sysinternals Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to get a list of all open handlers because is very possible a program have left one open handler but not use it.

With the [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) you can see what is open on this disk. Its a command prompt program, just type "handle" where you save it and thats all.

You can also type `handle >> results.txt` to save them on results.txt file and look them more easy.

The output is on this format:

```
Handle v3.46      
Copyright (C) 1997-2011 Mark Russinovich         
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com          

------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
System pid: 4 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM        
  934: File  (---)   C:\Documents and Settings\SQL_User\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat        
  938: File  (---)   C:\Documents and Settings\SQL_User\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat.LOG          
  93C: File  (---)   C:\Documents and Settings\SQL_User\NTUSER.dat.LOG         
  948: File  (---)   C:\Documents and Settings\SQL_User\NTUSER.DAT
```

Comment: I do not know why the -1 here.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. Download Microsoft's [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
2. Open the application
3. Click on the I/O graph

[image]

4. Mouse over your disk row

[image]

It should show you the executable running on that disk.

Comment: Process Explorer will show the process with the most Disk I/O. This is Disk I/O on all discs, not only on the one the questioner is interested in. Also a program can just keep a file open on an external disk, thus blocking it from being removable, but not read from or write to the file, so not having any Disk I/O.

Comment: Addition to Werner's comment: This is called a "handle" in Windows terminology. See Olivier's answer.